# search prefix method for binary search tree

Tags: java, binary-search-tree, tail-recursion

I am trying to implement a search prefix method for my dictionary program.It searches a binary search tree for a prefix- eg. "t" or "th" for "the". As of now, it is always returning false. What is so confusing is that I have a very similar method to look for whole words, and that works just fine.This method also uses very similar techniques to the usual BST methods. Any recommendations would be greatly appreciated.

```
private boolean recContainsPrefix(String prefixKey, BSTNode<String> tree){
    //base case
    if(tree==null)

    return false;
    //test if each node starts with the prefix.
    if(tree.getInfo().startsWith(prefixKey)){
        return true;
    }
    //recursive case.
    else if(prefixKey.compareTo(tree.getInfo())<0)
        return recContainsPrefix(prefixKey, tree.getLeft());
    //recursive case.
    else if(prefixKey.compareTo(tree.getInfo())>0)
        return recContainsPrefix(prefixKey, tree.getRight());

    else{
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Try `if (tree==null) {return false;}` instead, because I think that empty line under the if statement is affecting the code flow.

Comment: Thanks so very much more the suggestion! however this does not seem to work.

Comment: Sorry if it sounds stupid but can you show what does getInfo() return for a node in a tree. Since I am doubting the comparison 
`if(tree.getInfo().startsWith(prefixKey)){
        return true;
    }` for which if I go top down the string would never be satisfied.
Like 't' would never start with 'th'...'th' would never start with 'the'...

Answer (score 0):

Since its using recursion the tail condition is never met in the `bottom up recursion` for

```
if(tree.getInfo().startsWith(prefixKey))
 { 
   return true; 
   }
```

If so reverse the condition to :

```
if(prefixKey.startsWith(tree.getInfo()))
     { 
       return true; 
       }
```

Comment: thank you! Do you know of any way to fix this issue?